# Stex - an iOS application for Stack Exchange

Tags: app, iphone, ipad, ios

## Stex

---

This app is currently still under development, and as a result is not on the app store and doesn't have all features up and running.
To test for yourself, or contribute, check out [the repository on GitHub](http://github.com/chrisl212/Stex). The goal is to implement all features of the Stack Exchange network natively on the iPhone (and later the iPad) for all websites.

### License

Stex's source code is available under the [MIT License](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)

Screenshots (Click each for a larger image):

[image: Main Screen]
          [image: StackOverflow]

Comment: Not to discourage you, but [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/220264/help-us-test-the-alpha-version-of-our-ios-app) is something you should know.

Comment: Thanks for showing me that, I'll still keep this going though.